# How to make a full-screen overlay when clicking menu button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a menu button, which I want to trigger a full-screen nav overlay when clicked. I then want it to disappear when the button is clicked again.

As you can see I already have the menu button animation set up, I just can't figure out how to add and toggle an overlay nav.

Thanks

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNEBVE

```
    <header class="container">
  <a id="hamburger-icon" href="#" title="Menu">
      <span class="line line-1"></span>
      <span class="line line-2"></span>
      <span class="line line-3"></span>
  </a>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Page content</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @O. Eliel, refer this pen http://codepen.io/PaulVanO/pen/XJYGNQ

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a simple `toggle()` to a nav element.

with both examples you can just add a `<nav></nav>` before the `.hamburger-icon`

you can see an simple example here, the `toggle()` will just toggle the `display` from `none` to `block`, no fanciness:

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/aNEjgv

The JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
  var nav = $('nav');
  hamburger.click(function() {
    nav.toggle();
     hamburger.toggleClass('active');
     return false;
  });
});
```

and the CSS

```
nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Personally, if you'd like animation on the `nav` too, I would toggle a class on the nav, aslong as you have a `max-height` of `0` on its initial state you can give it a little opacity fade or give it a little slide-in effect with a top offset when it toggles in.

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/vGpaoZ

The JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
  var nav = $('nav');
  hamburger.click(function() {
    nav.toggleClass('shown');
     hamburger.toggleClass('active');
     return false;
  });
});
```

and the CSS

```
nav {
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav.shown {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: none
}
```

and to stop body scrolling i normally toggle a class on the `body` and `html` of `noScroll`. Here's an example of the CSS:

```
html.noScroll, body.noScroll {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the JS would contain:

```
$('body, html').toggleClass('noScroll');
```

Obviously you could add the `$('body, html')` into a var lke you have with the hamburger icon and nav.

Comment: Great, thanks. How can I disable scrolling once the overlay is shown?

Comment: I've just updated the original answer :) Feel free to upvote and mark as answer ;)

Comment: If I want the overlay to be slightly transparent by setting the opacity to say 0.7, how come the text is also going transparent? Can i set the transparency to just the background colour?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXMaEE

Comment: You'll need to set the opacity to one still (as thats the whole element), you can use RGBA to give just the background opacity, like `background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)`

here's an updated example: http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/VayGpM